# Keycloak Redirecting URL

Tags: reactjs, docker, frontend, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

i'm building a web application using react.js in my frontend , i'm trying to implement keycloak to secure my app, everyting is working correctly except the redirecting url i set up the code to redirect me automatically into an /Admin component but it keeps redirecting me to /Home.

I created a PrivateRoute.js file to setup keycloak

```
import { useKeycloak } from "@react-keycloak/web";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"; // Import useNavigate

const PrivateRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const { keycloak } = useKeycloak();
  const isLoggedIn = keycloak.authenticated;

  const navigate = useNavigate(); // Initialize the useNavigate hook

  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    navigate("/Home"); // Use useNavigate for redirection
    return null; // Return null since you're navigating
  }

  return children;
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

and i wrapped the /Admin route into  but it's not recognized

```
 <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/Home" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/Feedbacklist" element={<Feedbacklist />} />
            <Route path="/Add" element={<Addfeedback />} />
            <Route path="/AdminCollab" element={<AdminCollab />} />
            <Route path="/AdminComments" element={<AdminComments />} />
            <Route
             path="/Admin"
             element={
               <PrivateRoute>
                 <Admin />
               </PrivateRoute>
             }
           />
      </Routes>
```

i'm getting stuck on the home page after successful authentication and the redirection to the /Admin component is not working as expected